# how to get only the nouns from a sentence

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize, keyword, pos-tagger

I'm trying to find out which nouns exist in a sentence, i'm using pos_tag from nltk but it's not working very well
here is my code/function

```
def Noun(sentence):
    lista=[]
    words=(word_tokenize(sentence))
    pos=pos_tag(words)
    for i in range(len(pos)):
        if((pos[i][1].startswith('N'))):
            lista.append(pos[i][0])
        else:
            pass
    return pos,lista
```

for example :
tweet="let's talk to Thomas and check if he will come to the party"
Noun(tweet)
expected :

```
output: ['Thomas','party']
```

what i got:

```
['let', 'talk', 'Thomas', 'party'])
```

Comment: Actually, your output seems a noun list. `pos_tag`function provides these result: `[('let', 'NN'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('talk', 'NN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('Thomas', 'NNP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('check', 'VB'), ('if', 'IN'), ('he', 'PRP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('come', 'VB'), ('to', 'TO'), ('the', 'DT'), ('party', 'NN')]`

Comment: that'S right, but if you look into these result, let and talk are recognized as a noun which is not correct, that'S why i'm asking where is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in your code. The algorithm "pos_tag" using is the reason for the wrong output.
It shows those four word as noun:

```
[('let', 'NN'), ("'s", 'POS'), ('talk', 'NN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('Thomas', 'NNP'), ('and', 'CC'), ('check', 'VB'), ('if', 'IN'), ('he', 'PRP'), ('will', 'MD'), ('come', 'VB'), ('to', 'TO'), ('the', 'DT'), ('party', 'NN'), ('.', '.')]
```

You can try unigram tagging, n-gram tagging etc.
Follow this link for detailed info: https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html

Comment: Thank you! i fixed it using n-gram tagging